# PrimeNG upload and save file when form is submitted

Tags: php, image, upload, primeng, angular6

I'm using [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload) in angular 6 project in form which has other fields too. I can select image and upload it on server by clicking upload button but I need it to upload image when complete form is submitted on server. My code is a below:

```
<p-fileUpload 
   name="myfile[]" 
   url="{{uploadPhotoUrl}}"
   accept="image/*"
   chooseLabel="Blog Image"
   invalidFileTypeMessageDetail="Upload Only Images">
</p-fileUpload>
```

Form has other input fields and a submit button at the end. I've also tried to use following attributes but don't know how can I use them to send selected file with form to server.

```
(onUpload)="onUpload($event)" customUpload=true
```

Answer (score 0):

My current understanding is that you fundamentally cannot do this with the PrimeNG file upload component. The very nature of the component is to upload the file asynchronously meaning you aren't getting any of the rest of the form submission with it. You could use stateful mechanisms on the server side to keep the requests associated, but inherently the upload portion is not capable of including the rest of the form fields like a native file upload would.